# asynchronous scope property in directive using parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive

Still getting my head round angularJs, making progress, but im not sure if this problem is a directive related misunderstanding or a wider misunderstanding.

In my angular app, a directive is inheriting from a parent directives controller (my app isnt quite like this in reality but for the purpose of a simple jsfiddle its like that). The parent controller performs something async and i want the child template to update accordingly.

So the property is set after the child controller has gone through its compile/link process.
This property is already bound to the child template so when it updates why does the template not update? or what do i need to do to make this happen?

As i mentioned code is simplified greatly (the async bit is actually a service with an $http call and the template is far more complex and i need to use this property in a repeater etc) but this is in essence what my apps code looks like at the moment.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2LeGg/8/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <dashboard>
        <published></published>
    </dashboard>  
</div>
```

my angular javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('dashboard', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.foo = '';

            //this is actually to simulate an $http request
            $scope.get = function () {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $scope.foo = "hello";
                }, 1000);
            };

            $scope.get();

            $scope.bar="world";
        }
    };
})
.directive('published', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^dashboard',
        template : '<span>{{foo}} {{bar}}</span>',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log('scope', $scope); //can see foo in console so inheriting as expected
            console.log('scope.foo', $scope.foo); //not there so obviously because of async
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/967zF/

`setTimeout` do not fire a $digest , use `$timeout` instead:

```
app.directive('dashboard', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope,$timeout) {
            $scope.foo = '';

            $scope.get = function () {
                $timeout(function() {                    
                    $scope.foo = "hello";
                }, 1000);
            };

            $scope.get();

            $scope.bar="world";
        }
    };
})
```

---

#### A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MP8DR/

Alternatively, You can also trigger a $digest like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.foo = "hello";
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: ok thanks. the timeout is just simulating an $http call in reality. Does $http not fire a $digest? (and thanks i see a bit more what $digest means now)

Comment: as when i apply your second suggestion when i use $http, it errors saying $digest is already in progress...

Comment: $http do triggers a digest so you dont need to do anything

Answer (score 2):

If you change your fiddle and inject `$timeout` and use that instead of setTimeout it would work.
This

`app.directive('dashboard', function ($timeout) {`

and

```
 $timeout(function() {
     $scope.foo = "hello";
 }, 1000);
```